# Has the Mathematica StackExchange uploader stopped working for anyone else?

Tags: discussion

The Mathematica StackExchange uploader stopped working after I installed V9. Has this happened for anyone else?

Comment: Are you using the trial version or the full version? It won't work with the trial version because import/export is disabled. You can ping Szabolcs (the developer) directly in chat about this.

Comment: Full version. I guess this is not a common problem.  I'll talk to Szabolcs.

Comment: As @rm said, it won't work with the trial version because the import/export functionality on which it relies is disabled.  Can you please email me (see my profile for the address) and tell me exactly what yo mean by "does not work"?  Does the palette show?  What happens when you try to upload?  Do you get any error messages?  What OS are you using?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe What exactly happens? I tested it intensively on V9 and it seems sometimes JLink forgets to start Java. When this happens, everything works normal except when you upload the image, then you get an error message. Does this happen in your case?

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Do you still have the problem?  If yes, can you please email me with the details I asked?

Comment: @halirutan I had the `InstallJava` problem today.  Not sure what was causing it as it was working without an explicit `InstallJava` before.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Are you still having this problem?  You didn't reply my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange uploader didn't work with the trial version of 9.0 (which I hastily installed one day before the regular version), and it does not work with the regular  version. I'm wondering whether the trial version installation, still on my machine, interfered with the full version.

I've also noticed that the Welcome screen of 8.0 displays improperly (see below):

[image: welcome 8]

---

The welcome screen for version 9 also displays improperly (the center of the screen is empty) and furthermore presents the following complaint:

[image: welcome 9]

Once I get past the welcome screen, I notice no other problems with version 9 (full version).

---

The welcome screen of the trial version, when first installed, presented no problems. However, ever since the full version was installed, the welcome screen for the trial version (not yet removed) has presented the same problem as the full version.

---

I notified WRI of the problem over the weekend and am awaiting an answer.